# PyQt PySide 2 QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyside2, qthread

I know this might be repeating the same question that someone else asked already, but I still don't understand what is happening actually. I have seen a lot of examples for multithreading in this forum and have compiled a dummy demo of what my actual application going to do. Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *

class Color(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, color):
        super(Color, self).__init__()
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(color))    
        self.setPalette(palette)

class Inlet_Thread(QThread):

    data = Signal(int)
    tabs = Signal(int)
    finish = Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._stopped = False
        self.init_timers()
        print('new thread')
        self.c = 0
        self.d = 0

    def init_timers(self):
        self.timer1 = QTimer(self)
        self.timer1.timeout.connect(self.routine)
        self.timer2 = QTimer(self)
        self.timer2.timeout.connect(self.routine2)

    def starter(self):
        self.timer1.start(1000)
        self.timer2.start(2000)

    def run(self):
        while not self._stopped:
            pass
        self.timer1.stop()
        self.timer2.stop()
        print('stopped')
        self.finish.emit()

    def routine(self):
        self.data.emit(self.c)
        self.c += 1
    
    def routine2(self):
        self.tabs.emit(self.d)
        self.d += 1

    @Slot()
    def stop(self):
        self._stopped = True

class Inlet_Worker(QObject):

    data = Signal(int)
    tabs = Signal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._stopped = False
        self._registered = False
        self.init_timers()
        self.c = 0
        self.d = 0

    def init_timers(self):
        self.timer1 = QTimer(self)
        self.timer1.timeout.connect(self.routine)
        self.timer2 = QTimer(self)
        self.timer2.timeout.connect(self.routine2)

    def starter(self):
        self.timer1.start(1000)
        self.timer2.start(2000)

    def routine(self):
        self.data.emit(self.c)
        self.c += 1
        
    def routine2(self):
        self.tabs.emit(self.d)
        self.d += 1

    @Slot()
    def stop(self):
        self.timer1.stop()
        self.timer2.stop()
        print('stopped')


class Window(QWidget):

    startSig = Signal()
    stopSig = Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dlg = Dialog()
        self.thread = None

        pagelayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        button_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.stacklayout = QStackedLayout()

        pagelayout.addLayout(button_layout)
        pagelayout.addLayout(self.stacklayout)

        self.button = QPushButton('Start')
        self.button2 = QPushButton('Stop')
        self.button3 = QPushButton('Window')
        button_layout.addWidget(self.button)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.button3)

        self.stacklayout.addWidget(Color("red"))
        self.stacklayout.addWidget(Color("yellow"))
        self.stacklayout.addWidget(Color("green"))

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.startThr2)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.stopThr)
        self.button3.clicked.connect(self.showDlg)

    @Slot(int)
    def switch_tab(self, d):
        idx = d % 3
        print(idx)
        self.stacklayout.setCurrentIndex(idx)

    def showDlg(self):
        if not self.dlg.isVisible():
            self.dlg.show()
    
    def startThr(self):
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Inlet_Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker.data.connect(self.dlg.update)
        self.worker.tabs.connect(self.switch_tab)
        self.stopSig.connect(self.worker.stop)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.starter)
        self.thread.start()

    def startThr2(self):
        if self.thread is None or not self.thread.isRunning():
            self.thread = Inlet_Thread()
            self.thread.started.connect(self.thread.starter)
            self.thread.data.connect(self.dlg.update)
            self.thread.tabs.connect(self.switch_tab)
            self.thread.finish.connect(self.finished)
            self.stopSig.connect(self.thread.stop)
            self.thread.start()

    def stopThr(self):
        self.stopSig.emit()

    def finished(self):
        print('thread finished')
        self.thread.quit()
        self.thread.wait()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        #self.stopThr()
        pass

class Dialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.text1 = QLabel("Label 1 : ")
        self.text2 = QLabel("Text2")
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.text1)
        layout.addWidget(self.text2)
        self.setGeometry(400, 100, 100, 50)

    @Slot(int)
    def update(self, sig):
        self.text2.setText(str(sig))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(750, 80, 300, 80)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

While the threading is performing fine, it returns an error:

```
QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

And if I use the Qobject and move it to a thread, an additional error appears

```
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

Can someone explain what is causing the error?

EDIT:
I changed the code to be more complex and show where each data will go. The reason I'm using Qtimer in a thread is that there are multiple signals to emit and the frequency and shape of each data is different. Since this code is only a simplification of my actual application, there might be some different parts. And if there are alternatives, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing: `startThr` is never called, so the `Inlet_Worker` class is not used. Besides, as explained in the [QThread documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details), "you must start and stop the timer in its thread; it is not possible to start a timer from another thread.". You either create the QTimer in the function that is executed from the thread, or you *move* to it. Unfortunately, it's not really clear from your question what you actually intend to do with that timer. Also remember that QThread is **not** "the thread", but an *interface* to threading.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I tried 2 methods of doing tasks in another thread (hence the 2 functions which I can just change which one I want to use). The first one makes a Qobject and moves it to another thread. The second one is to subclass the Qthread itself (which according to some stacks answers are not recommended). The original purpose of this application is to stream data and process it. The thread in another window is to plot the data. From what I read from other answers, I can start and stop threads using signals and slots which i tried here.

Comment: And why do you need a QTimer? Please provide a *detailed* explanation.

Comment: The reason I use the QTimer is that there are going to be multiple signals emitted from the thread at different rates, so might as well put the stream pull function in a Qtimer. For example, the signal for the plotter is every 200 ms and for processing is 500 ms. The data emitted is the same but has different array sizes. In the dummy code, I only put one Qtimer because I only want to know how to fix the error.

Comment: So, the thread is actually used to connect and receive data. Plot and processing get almost no benefit from threading (python doesn't allow concurrency), so you can probably leave the qtimer out of the thread. Otherwise, as already said, either create the timer *in* the function that is run in the thread, or use moveToThread. But I sincerely doubt that it would be necessary.

Comment: True that plot and processing don't get much benefits from threading. The only reason that I use QTimer is so that I can flexibly control the signal and data emitted (i need it for my original app). And as I said, this program is simplified since I only want to know what is causing the error. I'm pretty sure I create the timer in the object that is moved to the thread or did I misunderstand something? Sorry for this since I'm pretty new in pyqt